# KeyError: "['petal length'] not in index"

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having some issues with the index from a Pandas data frame. What I'm trying to do is load data from a csv file, create a Pandas data frame and then select specific columns from that data frame and convert it in to an array.

> *KeyError: "['petal length'] not in index"*

The code I'm using is

```
  import pandas as pd
  import numpy as np
  data = pd.read_csv('iris.csv')
  x = np.array(data[['sepal length', 'petal length']])
```

This is the table:

[image: Pandas Data Frame]

Using `reindex` will create missing values for the columns.

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Can you post the output of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: it seems data are [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/tests/data/iris.csv)

Comment: But the image shows the column names exactly like the OP entered.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for helping out. The output of `print(df.columns)` is: `Index([u'sepal length', u' sepal width', u' petal length', u' petal width',
       u' species'],
      dtype='object')`

Answer (score 2):

You need check column names:

```
print (data.columns)
Index(['SepalLength', 'SepalWidth', 'PetalLength', 'PetalWidth', 'Name'], dtype='object')
```

so for selecting use:

```
x = np.array(data[['SepalWidth', 'PetalWidth']])
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out! Unfortunately the solution did not work.